# Deleting/Creating Categories.. new category/products not appearing on webpage

Tags: category-products

I deleted a category and created another.  The old category with 1 item is still appearing on my webpage and the new category isn't showing up on the webpage nor are any of my products assigned under that category.

Comment: Have you tried re-indexing and clearing your cache?

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to re-index/clear cache.

You can reindex in:

```
system/index management/
```

Clear cache in:

```
system/cache management/
```